# How to hide PayPal logo in adroid devices using card.io plug-in for Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, card.io

According to the plugin documentation, it seems there isn't a configuration option to hide the PayPal logo in the card detail Action bar. However the card.io SDK for android has an option to do it:

https://card-io.github.io/card.io-Android-SDK/io/card/payment/CardIOActivity.html#EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON

Is there a way to hide this logo?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way.

First, you have to remove the android platform to download all dependencies from scratch:

```
ionic cordova platform remove Android
```

Then, add the card.io cordova plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add card.io.cordova.mobilesdk
```

After taht, in "plugins/card.io.cordova.mobilesdk/src/android" you have to make changes in 2 files:

**build.gradle**
replace

```
dependencies {
  compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.4.0'
}
```

By this:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
}
```

In file **CardIOCordovaPlugin.java** you have to add the new configuration option EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON:

```
  private void scan(JSONArray args) throws JSONException {
        Intent scanIntent = new Intent(this.activity, CardIOActivity.class);
        JSONObject configurations = args.getJSONObject(0);
        // customize these values to suit your needs.
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_EXPIRY, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "requireExpiry", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CVV, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "requireCVV", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_POSTAL_CODE, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "requirePostalCode", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_MANUAL_ENTRY, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "suppressManual", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_RESTRICT_POSTAL_CODE_TO_NUMERIC_ONLY, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "restrictPostalCodeToNumericOnly", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_KEEP_APPLICATION_THEME, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "keepApplicationTheme", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_REQUIRE_CARDHOLDER_NAME, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "requireCardholderName", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_CARDIO_LOGO, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "useCardIOLogo", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_INSTRUCTIONS, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "scanInstructions", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_NO_CAMERA, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "noCamera", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SCAN_EXPIRY, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "scanExpiry", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_OR_LOCALE, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "languageOrLocale", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_GUIDE_COLOR, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "guideColor", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_CONFIRMATION, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "suppressConfirmation", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_HIDE_CARDIO_LOGO, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "hideCardIOLogo", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_SUPPRESS_SCAN, this.getConfiguration(configurations, "suppressScan", false)); // default: false
        scanIntent.putExtra(CardIOActivity.EXTRA_USE_PAYPAL_ACTIONBAR_ICON, false); // THIS IS THE NEW OPTION
        this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, scanIntent, REQUEST_CARD_SCAN);
    }
```

In this case I hardcoded this new option to false, but you can implement the getConfiguration() method to set this option from your ionic page.

Once you make these 2 changes, add again your android platform to your project (to download the latest SDKs v5.5.1):

```
ionic cordova platfrom add android
```

That's all, the PayPal logo has gone!